# T-sql How to get the Id associated with max date in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a temp table named #t that will hold data that looks like shown below. How can I query to get the result desired I'm searching for the testId associated with the max(expirationDate) for each employee (empId)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `subquery` :

```
select t.*
from #t t
where expirationdate = (select max(t1.expirationdate) 
                        from #t t1 
                        where t1.empid = t.empid
                       );
```